# Getting data through pivot table using hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello i have these three models:

**User.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Kodeine\Acl\Traits\HasRole;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, HasRole;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var stringSS
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'is_active'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function bankBranch()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\BankBranch', 'bank_branches_users', 'user_id', 'branch_id');
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permissions', 'permission_user', 'user_id', 'permission_id');
    }

}
```

**Bank.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bank extends Model {

    protected $table = 'bank_details';

    public function branches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\BankBranch', 'bank_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\User', 'App\Models\BankBranch');
    }

}
```

**BankBranch.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BankBranch extends Model {

    protected $table = 'bank_branches';

    public function bank()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Bank', 'bank_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User', 'bank_branches_users', 'branch_id', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

Okay now in my application i have the following relationships:
1. User belongs to Many Bank Branches.
2. Bank Branch belongs to one Bank.
3. BankBranch has many users.

Now when a user logs in i want them to only be able to see other users within the same bank branch as the user.

Meaning on my admin->user page i want a list of users in the same branch as the logged in user only.

Unless the logged in user belongs to many other branches, then it should display all the users in the branches the logged in user belongs to.

I am having great difficulty representing this in my eloquent models and fetching the data through my controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get user bankBranches ids:

```
$branchIds = Auth::user()->bankBranch()->get()->lists('id');
```

than gettting all users that belongs to this branches:

```
$usersInBranches = BankBranch::whereIn('id',$branchedIds)->with('users')->get();
```

or:

```
$usersInBranches = User::whereHas('bankBranch', function($query) use ($branchIds) {
 $query->whereIn('id',$branchIds);
})->get();
```

edit or even better:

```
$usersInBranches = User::whereHas('bankBranch', function($query){
 $query->whereIn('id',Auth::user()->bankBranch()->lists('id'));
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting Integrity constraint violation, ambiguous column 'id' in field list.  How do i fix this please?

Comment: All of them actually.

Comment: Think it has to do with this: Auth::user->bankBranch()->lists('id')

Comment: Auth::user->bankBranch()->get()->lists("id"); this work?